# Caption of Table Clipping with table itself

Tags: formatting, tabularx

I'm getting started in LaTeX right now and have an issue with the caption of my table.
I'm using TabularX and the caption is clipping with the table itself. Could you maybe help me? Thank you!
[image]

I'm really sorry the formatting of the code doesn't seem to work I dont know why.

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,                           
    fontsize=11pt,                      
    parskip=half*,                      
    ]{scrartcl}                         

\begin{document}
    
\usepackage{tabularx}                   
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},             
            font={footnotesize},    
            labelsep=space,             
            format=hang,                    
            justification=raggedright,  
            singlelinecheck=false       
            ]{caption}              

\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=5pt, belowskip=-5pt}


\begin{table}[!ht]
\small
    \centering
    \captionof{table}[RFA-Analyseergebnisse des ausgefilterten Feststoff (Partikelretention 8-15µm)]{RFA-Analyseergebnisse des ausgefilterten Feststoff (Partikelretention 8-15µm)}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \hline
        \textbf{Al} & \textbf{Ni} & \textbf{Co} & \textbf{Mn} & \textbf{Cu} & \textbf{Fe} & \textbf{P} & \textbf{Ca} & \textbf{Si} \\ \hline
        10.49\% & 22.68\% & 11.74\% & 6.65\% & 1.29\% & 0.85\% & 0.79\% & 0.36\% & 0.22\% \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{RFA_Filterkuchen_1}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea why either as you don't show code that we can compile. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem and how you have tried to solve it.

Comment: You can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code for formatting code.  One tick mark works for inline code, but for a code block, you want three tick marks before and after, or four spaces in front of every line.  To do the latter, you can highlight the code and click `{}` (or ctrl-K).

Comment: But to follow up on the first comment, have you copy/pasted this code to make sure what you say happens does actually happen?  What you've given us has some errors, and doesn't result in the image you've shown.  This means you have some other code that you're using, and we can't really debug that.

Comment: if you use negative spaces you are explicitly programming over-printing. What did you want `belowskip=-5pt` to do ???

Comment: using `[!ht]` is not recommended, `!` is an over-ride for special cases, not something for routine use, and not including `p` makes it hard for latex to place the float

Comment: If you change your code in the question please make sure that you indicated where you have edited it. If someone answers and then you change the question how is anyone expected to know what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to getting rid of the questionable `belowskip=-5pt` option, you really ought to attempt to give your table a more open and inviting "look". I suggest you do so by (a) using the macros of the `booktabs` package to create well-spaced horizontal rules, (b) not **bold-facing** the items in the header row (and employ a package such as `mhchem` to typeset the chemical equations), and (c) moving the common `%` symbol from the data cells into the caption.

Incidentally, in view of the fact that the directive occurs within a `table` environment, it's not clear to me why you're using `\captionof{table}{...}` instead of just `\caption{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,                           
    fontsize=11pt,                      
    parskip=half*,                      
    ]{scrartcl}                         

%\usepackage{tabularx} % does not appear to be needed                  
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}, % you sure about this?
            labelfont = bf,       
            labelsep  = space,             
            format    = hang,                    
            justification=raggedright,  
            singlelinecheck=false       
            ]{caption}              
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0.5\baselineskip}
     % {aboveskip=5pt, belowskip=-5pt} % huh?
\usepackage{siunitx,mhchem,booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \small
    \caption{RFA-Analyseergebnisse des ausgefilterten 
             Feststoffs (Partikelretention 
             8--15\,\unit{\micro\meter}), in \%}
    \label{RFA_Filterkuchen_1}
    
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{9}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
    \ce{Al} & \ce{Ni} & \ce{Co} & \ce{Mn} & \ce{Cu} &
    \ce{Fe} & \ce{P}  & \ce{Ca} & \ce{Si}   \\ 
    \midrule
    10.49 & 22.68 & 11.74 & 6.65 & 1.29 & 
     0.85 &  0.79 &  0.36 & 0.22   \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. I was planning to do the \ce{} formatting after. I use \captionof since it was part of a LaTeX Tutorial I saw

Answer (score 2):

I think You should just change the `belowskip` parametr from `-5pt` to `5pt`. However, You can use just `\caption` for the table.
*Also, I would reccomend You (as a begginer) to use this [wedsite](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) to create tables much easily*

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,                           
    fontsize=11pt,                      
    parskip=half*,                      
    ]{scrartcl}     

\usepackage{tabularx}                   
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},             
            font={footnotesize},    
            labelsep=space,             
            format=hang,                    
            justification=raggedright,  
            singlelinecheck=false       
            ]{caption}              

%\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=5pt, belowskip=5pt} % <--           

\begin{document}
    



\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\small
    
    \caption{RFA-Analyseergebnisse des ausgefilterten Feststoff (Partikelretention 8-15µm)}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
        \hline
        \textbf{Al} & \textbf{Ni} & \textbf{Co} & \textbf{Mn} & \textbf{Cu} & \textbf{Fe} & \textbf{P} & \textbf{Ca} & \textbf{Si} \\ \hline
        10.49\% & 22.68\% & 11.74\% & 6.65\% & 1.29\% & 0.85\% & 0.79\% & 0.36\% & 0.22\% \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \label{RFA_Filterkuchen_1}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You had me until you recommended the use of tablegenerators.com. The LaTeX code produced by that site is very difficult to edit by hand.

Comment: @Mico partly agree, "very difficult to edit by hand" means You are going to do it later, but if You have done everything right You will not need to edit it again. I reccomend it only because I have been using it for a long time and can say that it is good tool for small tables like this.

Comment: The problem is that once a beginner starts using a site such as `tablegenerators.com`, they'll get stuck with path forever and they'll never learn how to create `tabular` environments on their own.

Comment: ok I will never recommend ```tablegenerators.com``` again

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in key `caption`.

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,                           
    fontsize=11pt,                      
    parskip=half*,                      
    ]{scrartcl}                         

\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\small
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}
     [ caption = { RFA-Analyseergebnisse des ausgefilterten Feststoff (Partikelretention 8-15µm) } ]
     {@{}ccccccccc@{}}
     \toprule
     \RowStyle[bold]{}
      Al & Ni & Co & Mn & Cu & Fe & P & Ca & Si \\
     \midrule
      10.49\% & 22.68\% & 11.74\% & 6.65\% & 1.29\% & 0.85\% & 0.79\% & 0.36\% & 0.22\% \\ 
     \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \label{RFA_Filterkuchen_1}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

I would write your table on the following way:

- for table use `tabularray` package with `X[c]` columns
- for table lines rules of `booktabs` package
- in the second row I would write data as quantities as is proposed in `siunitx` package
  . Packages `booktabs` and `siunitx` are loaded as `tabularray` libraries:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,
               fontsize=11pt,
               parskip=half*,
               ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font={footnotesize},
            labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=space,
            format=hang,
            justification=raggedright,
            singlelinecheck=false
            ]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\caption{RFA-Analyseergebnisse des ausgefilterten Feststoff (Partikelretention 8-15µm)}
\label{RFA_Filterkuchen_1}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { *{9}{X[c]} },
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries}
                }
    \toprule
A   &   Ni  &   Co  &   Mn  &   Cu  &   Fe  &   P   &   Ca  &   Si  \\
    \midrule
\qty{10.49}{\%} & \qty{22.68}{\%}   & \qty{11.74}{\%}   &  
 \qty{6.65}{\%} &  \qty{1.29}{\%}   & \qty{0.85}{\%}    &
 \qty{0.79}{\%} &  \qty{0.36}{\%}   & \qty{0.22}{\%}    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]